# how to get ordered queries in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, animal and people, I am making a query using UNION to get a combined list of both tables, but I want every 4 animals I look 1 person, that is:

Results:

```
*animal 1
animal 2
animal 3
animal 4*
**person 1**
*animal 5
animal 6
animal 7
animal 8*
**person 2**
etc...
```

Is there any way to do it?

Please help me!

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Pretty easy using row_number() (and some math) in Sql Server or any modern database engine. Unfortunately, MySql hasn't really counted as a modern relational database for over a decade. It's missing the windowing functions required for this, as well as lateral joins, CTEs/recursion (as of the current stable release), full join, materialized views, and more.

Comment: "Is there any way to do it?"  Yes.  Nearly anything is possible given enough time and money.  Strawberry's comment gives you the next steps so comments/answer can be more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO: using rextester](http://rextester.com/IWE58923)

Using user variables you can often simulate analytics in enterprise databases (though not nearly as efficient)

We generate derived table (UnionSeq) to generate the needed sequencing and then add our own formula to multiply the generated row_number for persons to be 4 * greater so it will fit in after the 4th animal and use column aliased seq to determine that animals come before people in the order.  Then we select from the derived table to apply the needed ordering.

```
SELECT Name 
FROM (SELECT ID, Name, (@p:=@P+1)*4 Row_num, 'b' as Seq 
      FROM person
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @p:=0) a
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ID, Name, @a:=@a+1, 'a' as seq 
      FROM animal
      CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a:=0) b) UnionSeq
ORDER BY Row_num, Seq
```

Giving us:

```
+----+----------+
|    |   Name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Animal 1 |
|  2 | Animal 2 |
|  3 | Animal 3 |
|  4 | Animal 4 |
|  5 | Person 1 |
|  6 | Animal 5 |
|  7 | Animal 6 |
|  8 | Animal 7 |
|  9 | Animal 8 |
| 10 | Person 2 |
| 11 | Animal 9 |
| 12 | Person 3 |
+----+----------+
```

Your sample data doesn't show what to do if there are disproportionate numbers of people to animals; so in my demo I just let each table show all data based on a pattern irrespective if the 4x1 pattern can't be maintained.  In this example you can see Animal 9 is followed by person 3 even though there aren't 4 animals.  and if there was a person 4 it would follow person 3 as there would be no more animals.

It's not magic; it's math and general SQL processes and order of operations.